# OLS and Probit Model regarding a dummy variable being dropped

Tags: regression, least-squares, stata, probit

I've been trying to run a regression using a probit model, but I keep getting a dummy variable being dropped from the regression (in Stata's output) because it predicts the success perfectly. The OLS estimation, though, does not drop it. Why is that so?

Comment: Does the OLS estimator perhaps drop a *different* variable?

Comment: It does not. I'm really puzzled.

Comment: That is strange (+1), because one would expect collinearity not to depend on the response variable.  How, exactly, do you know that collinearity *per se* is the reason Stata is dropping the variable?  Have you generated any collinearity diagnostics?  (Perhaps--I'm speculating heavily--Stata uses different code or different thresholds to deal with collinearity in its regression and logistic regression functions and your data might be right below the threshold for one and right above the threshold for the other.) Another thought: is it possible some *data* are being dropped by one procedure?

Comment: I'm sorry. I read the wrong message from the output! The variable is dropped because it predicts success perfectly. But why would the OLS estimation not drop it?

Comment: @whuber, I changed the question, considering that I was not correctly understanding the error previously.

Comment: Can you include the stata output in the question?